# Is there a way to make Gmail canned response save distribution list ('to'='cc')?

Tags: gmail-canned-response

On a daily basis we must send out email alerts (e.g., shipment notice to customers), where Gmail's canned response feature is a good tool to ensure standard email body is used. However we could not figure out a way to save distribution lists for each canned response saved. This would be a very powerful tool ensuring that no one is left out from the alert. Is there a way to do that?